# C# WPF Call method from a closing window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a method in a page `public partial class pagThreads : Page` for data loading from DB to DataGrid:

```
public void dbReadData()
{
    DbAccess db = new DbAccess();
    lista = db.GetThreads();
    dgrThreads.ItemsSource = lista;
}
```

To edit those data I'm opening another window like this (by double clicking on DataGrid row):

```
private void dgrThreads_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    wndSabThrEdit wndSabThrEdit = new wndSabThrEdit();
    wndSabThrEdit.ShowDialog();
}
```

After editing I can save the data by updating the record in DB like this:

```
public void SaveSettings()
{
    DbAccess dbAccess = new();
    dbAccess.UpdateSabThreads();
    string message = "Settings saved.";
    string title = "Information";
    MessageBoxResult result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    if(result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        Close();    
    }
}
```

The question is: How to trigger the method `dbReadData()` again to refresh the data in the the DataGrid, for example after closing the editing window? I will be gratefull for help. Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just call dbReadData after `wndSabThrEdit.ShowDialog();`?

Comment: Hi Klaus, it  will be before editing and saving the data in DB. I was wondering to make it somewhere here: `if(result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        Close();    
    }` but in this window i can't access `dbReadData()` method

Comment: Is  SaveSettings a method in the Window that's opened'?

Comment: page `pagThreads` owns DataGrid and `dbReadData()` and window `wndSabThrEdit` owns `SaveSettings()` method

Comment: Your first suggestion Klaus Gutter was good, thank you! I didn't know that the code stops in `ShowDialog()`..

Answer (score 2):

From your comment it looks like you think that putting

```
dbReadData();
```

after

```
wndSabThrEdit.ShowDialog();
```

would run immediately.

It won't.

`ShowDialog()` blocks, and the code will only continue to `dbReadData();` after the Window has closed.

So just change to:

```
private void dgrThreads_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    wndSabThrEdit wndSabThrEdit = new wndSabThrEdit();
    wndSabThrEdit.ShowDialog();
    SaveSettings();
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. It works like it should!!! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

If `wndSabThrEdit` inherits from `Window` it has a closing event that you can subscribe to:

```
wndSabThrEdit.Closing += (_,_) => dbReadData();
wndSabThrEdit.ShowDialog();
```